# Use KeyValuePair<String, String> in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I want to run this normal loop in Parallel using Parallel.For or `Parallel.ForEach<>`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> symbol in symbolsConfigured){..}
```

I've been using elsewhere like this -

```
Parallel.ForEach(sig.Products, dbp =>
            {...}
```

But I can't think of how to write this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way:

```
Parallel.ForEach(symbolsConfigured, kvp =>
            {...});
```

The compiler will infer the callback's parameter type, just like any other call.